# How transform xml element and sub elements attributes values into one new element and sub element

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have been looking for a good documentation to explain this without success. 
This my problem:

this are my requirements

- root element must be change the name (this is done),
- Only one attribute name in second level element should element should be transformed in a newelement.
- Second level element and the rest of its attributes should be removed
- All the attributes in third level element (inside second level element) are transformed into a second level element.
- Third level element should be removed.

Current

```
<list>

<type name="drum" acustic="true" pieces="5" >
    <part name="pearl" id="0" version="0" displayOrder="0" customizationLevel="basic" />
    <part name="dw" id="1" version="0" displayOrder="0" customizationLevel="basic" />
</type>

<type name="guitar" acustic="true" pieces="1" >
    <part name="fender" id="0" version="0" displayOrder="0" customizationLevel="basic" />       
</type>
```

desired

```
<instrumentList>
    <instrument>
    <instrumentType>drum</instrumentType>
    <instrumentID>0</instrumentID>
    <instrumentBrand>pearl</instrumentBrand>
    <version>0</version>
    <displayOrder>0</displayOrder>
    <customizationLevel>basic</customizationLevel>
    </instrument>

    <intrument>
    <instrumentType>drum</instrumentType>
    <instrumentID>1</instrumentID>
    <instrumentBrand>dw</instrumentBrand>
    <version>0</version>
    <displayOrder>0</displayOrder>
    <customizationLevel>basic</customizationLevel>
    </instrument>
    <instrument>    
    <instrumentType>guitar</instrumentType>
    <instrumentID>0</instrumentID>
    <instrumentBrand>fender</instrumentBrand>
    <version>0</version>
    <displayOrder>0</displayOrder>
    <customizationLevel>basic</customizationLevel>
    </instrument>
</instrumentList>
```

So I have followed the following tutorial and threads without success
[Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733880/convert-attribute-value-into-element)
[Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655411/converting-xml-elements-to-xml-attributes-using-xslt)

I can do part of it but not all.
I'm sure there is something I'm not understanding here especially with the removing elements and creating new elements and using some of the attributes, not all of them.
Even if someone could point me with a good reference where I can understand how the xslt parse the xml so I can have a better idea since all the examples I found they transform every single attribute or element and that unfortunately is not my case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please add your example input and output xml. And decide fthe xlst version xslt-1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: ok I finally could add the xml. Thanks for the help

Comment: You are sure `instrument` should become the root element? Looks strange to me.

Comment: that's not relevant really since I can't put the real xml I created some idea. What is important is actually the changes on the hierachy which I just found  a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706946/change-flat-xml-structure-to-hierarchical-structure-with-xslt) post that seems to be related but it's still simpler than this one.

Comment: Ok, understood why you said that. You are right Instrument shouldn't be the root element. Should be the instrument container only, the root should be something like instrimentList

Answer (score 1):

Well, you would start off by having a generic template that turned attributes into elements, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
   <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But looking at your requirements, certain attributes need to be renamed as elements, and so you would then write specific templates for these. For example, the **@id** element looks like it is to be renamed as **InstrumentId**

```
<xsl:template match="@id">
   <instrumentID>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </instrumentID>
</xsl:template>
```

The only little bit of extra work needed is with the template that matches the **part** element is that you need to output an **instrumentType** element whose value is equal to the parent attribute. Apart from that you would just need to select all the attribute elements to transform

```
<xsl:template match="part">
   <instrumentType>
      <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
   </instrumentType>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

For the second level **type** element, you can let XSLT's built-in templates handle it.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="list">
      <instrument>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </instrument>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="part">
      <instrumentType>
         <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
      </instrumentType>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@id">
      <instrumentID>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </instrumentID>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@name">
      <instrumentBrand>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </instrumentBrand>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML (assuming a closing **list** tag), the following is output

```
<instrument>
   <instrumentType>drum</instrumentType>
   <instrumentBrand>pearl</instrumentBrand>
   <instrumentID>0</instrumentID>
   <version>0</version>
   <displayOrder>0</displayOrder>
   <customizationLevel>basic</customizationLevel>

   <instrumentType>drum</instrumentType>
   <instrumentBrand>dw</instrumentBrand>
   <instrumentID>1</instrumentID>
   <version>0</version>
   <displayOrder>0</displayOrder>
   <customizationLevel>basic</customizationLevel>

   <instrumentType>guitar</instrumentType>
   <instrumentBrand>fender</instrumentBrand>
   <instrumentID>0</instrumentID>
   <version>0</version>
   <displayOrder>0</displayOrder>
   <customizationLevel>basic</customizationLevel>
</instrument>
```

Comment: well this is much better than I thought. Billion thanks and just one more question, since I'll probably will need to keep doing this xslt transformations could you reference me a book or link where to learn this stuff in depth. Most of the Tutorial I have followed they skip too much stuff. (+1 for the fantastic answer)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858345/xsltwhich-is-the-best-tutorial-you-would-like-to-recommend/2306680#2306680 which contains some links and books. Some of the books are written by Michael Kay who is very active on StackOverflow.